# Iphone Log Out from App problem

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, logout

i have an application based on an navigation controller. At first, it presents a Modal View with the Log In interface. After the user logs in, i dismiss this view and present the rootViewController.

Then, in the nav bar i have a button in order to show the Profile view in wich i can log out.

The problem is the following. When i press log out in the Profile View i do two things:

- Present a new Modal View with the log in screen.
- Pop the profile view controller.

But for a moment, i can see the pop action and the RootViewController before the Log In View is shown.

How can avoid this behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify that you do not want to see the animation. Where are you popping the last view controller from?

It should probably be something like this
`[navController popViewControllerAnimated:NO];`

Comment: How about pushing another a plain view controller with a black background with no animation before passing control to the modal view?

Comment: Have you tried popping the view controller prior to dimissing the modal view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Hey,
I think you must have the `animated` flag either on `- (void)dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated` or
on `- (UIViewController *)popViewControllerAnimated:(BOOL)animated` set to `YES` so you are actually able to see it switching views. If you change them to `NO` the "Log in" view will come up right away.

I hope this is useful for you.

Regards

Comment: yes. i set the flag to NO but i see the rootviewcontroller when i pop the view